# Moving spark.components.Application's ControlBar to its bottom

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5, skin

How can Application's ControlBar be moved to its bottom in Flex 4.5 ?

The [Adobe doc](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf62d75-7fff.html) says only:

> By default, the ApplicationSkin class defines the control bar area to
>   appear at the top of the content area of the Application container
>   with a grey background. Create a custom skin to change the default
>   appearance of the control bar.

So I look at [spark.skins.spark.ApplicationSkin](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/skins/spark/ApplicationSkin.html) and there is a controlBarGroup (does it hold the ControlBar contents?), but I don't know how to move it from top to the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you have to do is create a custom skin class. In FlashBuilder (FB) there's an option to create one automatically, but in essence it's just a class like any other.

In FB, right-click somewhere in your project and select 'New > MXML Skin'

[image]

Then fill in the wizard form as follows:

[image]

Otherwise just create a new .mxml file and copy/paste the code from `spark.skins.spark.ApplicationSkin` into it.

Then in your application assign the skin class you've just created:

```
<s:Application ... skinClass="skins.MyApplicationSkin" />
```

Now let's edit your newly created skin class. This is the part that is of interest to you (I'll cut out some pieces to make it clearer):

```
<s:Group left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0">
    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout gap="0" horizontalAlign="justify" />
    </s:layout>

    <s:Group id="topGroup" minWidth="0" minHeight="0"
                includeIn="normalWithControlBar, disabledWithControlBar" >

        <!-- some graphic elements here -->

        <s:Group id="controlBarGroup" left="0" right="0" top="1" bottom="1" ...>
            <s:layout>
                <s:HorizontalLayout ... />
            </s:layout>
        </s:Group>
    </s:Group>

    <s:Group id="contentGroup" width="100%" height="100%" ... />

</s:Group>
```

Almost there. Now all we need to do, is move that 'topGroup' beneath the 'contentGroup'. 'topGroup' contains some graphics + the controlBarGroup. 'contentGroup' is the area where all components will be inserted that you but in you application .mxml file.

```
<s:Group left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0">
    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout gap="0" horizontalAlign="justify" />
    </s:layout>

    <s:Group id="contentGroup" width="100%" height="100%" ... />

    <s:Group id="topGroup" minWidth="0" minHeight="0"
                includeIn="normalWithControlBar, disabledWithControlBar" >

        <!-- some graphic elements here -->

        <s:Group id="controlBarGroup" left="0" right="0" top="1" bottom="1" ...>
            <s:layout>
                <s:HorizontalLayout ... />
            </s:layout>
        </s:Group>
    </s:Group>

</s:Group>
```

Comment: Thank you for the good explanation, this works! And I even changed the background fill to gradient by modifying the "backgroundRect".

Answer (score 0):

You could try moving the control bar group under the content group and it should behave as expected, especially if you look at the parent group's layout(vertical).
If you would like to exercise even more control over it, override the `partAdded` method.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I "move the control bar group under the content group"?

Comment: Get access to the source code of the spark.skins.spark.ApplicationSkin. Copy it and paste it into a new component that you created(say for example MySkin.) After that move the part of the code associated controlBarGroup under the Group with the id contentGroup and that should be all.